# Counting/assigning group order to observations within groups for multilevel groups?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I'm working on a time-series analysis I have a dataset that contains at least two indexing variables (in this case ID and Year). After sorting by ID and Year:

```
ID  Year Grade 
1   1990  89
1   1991  76
1   1991  29
2   2001  99
2   2001  46
2   2001  69
2   2003  95
```

I would like to group by these variables and assign the order of appearance of the second level group within first group to each observation. In other words, I'd like to generate the "period" variable below:

```
ID  Year Grade period 
1   1990 89     1 
1   1991 76     2
1   1991 29     2
2   2001 99     1
2   2001 46     1
2   2001 69     1
2   2003 95     2
```

Comment: You should add your answer as part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a round about way to go about this. First sort your level variables

```
full_data = full_data.sort_values(by=['ID','Year'],ascending = [True, True])
```

create a binary variable that indicates the first observation in each 2 level group

```
full_data['temp'] = (full_data.groupby(['ID','Year']).cumcount() == 0).astype(int)
```

then calculate the cumulative sum of that variable within each first level group.

```
full_data['period'] = full_data.groupby(['ID']).cumsum()['temp']
```

This answer does not work if you do not sort first. Being fairly inexperienced with Pandas it took me a while to figure this out. It works but I'm curious if anyone has a simpler solution.